# Adding elements to ExpandableListView only using XMLs

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to develop few sample screens (without functionality). I dont want to use much java code for that, i want to use only XMLs (either Strings.xml or Androidxmlfiles). In my flow i have an ExpandableListView to which i have to add some text items. Any one please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to populate ExpandableListView with your own contents using XML only. 
Eclipse UI designer, I believe, shows some elements as if they are added but they go like 'Item 1' 'Item 2' etc basically for the developer to see where the list sits on the screen.

If you already have UI flow what's the reason to have even more screen samples though...

Comment: Thanks Alex. My application has not yet developed but i have a clear "flow of that in my mind". I need screens as it is a request from my boss. ;)